# What are the consequences of choosing structures over channels?

Tags: sections

I want to build an international directory of fishing port centres in Craft. Each port will have the same custom fields and be geocoded.

The documentation [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries) just doesn't make clear the ramifications of choosing channels versus structures. I get the ordering of structures which makes me think structures is the right approach. But do we lose out in search/RSS/templating down the line or are all entries equal in terms of there later usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All entries are equal. The only differences between Structures and Channels are that Structures are manually sortable and can be nested under other entries. Channels sort by Post Date by default. Unless you are doing a stream of entries (like blog posts or events), structures are a good way to go.